Disable a Symfony command from vendor
I have a Symfony project with Doctrine. Doctrine has a command doctrine:schema:update.
It gets used too often, lets say out of habits. After running the doctrine:schema:update all the migrations are messed up and I have to come and fix their development machine.
I want to disable that command (or at least make it not the easiest route), but cant figure out how (or even IF) i can do that.
I have tried:

Extend the UpdateSchemaCommand, give it the same COMMAND and throw an exception
Define it in my services.yaml as public:false
Define it in my services.yaml with a non-existing class (ugly, but working).

This all does nothing, each time the update command returns the default result.

Hmmm. Have you tried simply removing vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Command/Proxy/UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand.php? But seriously if the development team insists on using commands that they are not supposed to then you have bigger problems. Have you tried explain why you think the command is a bad idea? Or asking why they like to use it? Migrations are over-rated.

@Cerad According to question, the command is executed by mistake, and not implemented by the project. Also, I don't think it's wise to use a package manager and then fiddle manually with the files it creates, Composer or not.

Have you tried with an EventListener ? Like listeninig to console commands with ConsoleCommandEvent and then disable the execution of the command?

Its mostly the easiest route to fix a dev DB. Excepts its not, because its quick to do, but takes time to clean up the mess. Its a habbits which the users agree should be delt with. See my override as a reminder :) The exception would become something like "Nope, use migrations instead"

Notice the difference between UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand and UpdateSchemaCommand

You can disable the command this way with an EventListener:
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class CommandListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            ConsoleEvents::COMMAND => 'onConsoleCommand',
        ];
    }

    public function onConsoleCommand(ConsoleCommandEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->getCommand()->getName() === 'doctrine:schema:update') {
            $event->getOutput()->writeln('<error>The command doctrine:schema:update is disabled.</error>');
            $event->disableCommand(); 
        }
    }
}

And then enable it:
services:
  App\EventListener\DisableDoctrineSchemaUpdateListener:
    tags: [{name: 'kernel.event_subscriber'}]


It needed the services addition, but then it worked as expected :) And if someone really has to, its easy to enable if you know how

I agree! But when someone wants to go over the restrictions there is always a way I guess ;) At least that's a first "soft" layer to disable the command

<error>Command doctrine:schema:update is not supported in this project. Do blah blah instead.</error>
